# Is there an effective partitioning method when using reduceByKey in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, partitioning

When I use `reduceByKey` or `aggregateByKey`, I'm confronted with partition problems.

ex)`reduceBykey(_+_).map(code)`

Especially, if input data is skewed, the partitioning problem becomes even worse when using the above methods.

So, as a solution to this, I use `repartition` method.

For example, http://dev.sortable.com/spark-repartition/ is similar.

This is good for partition distribution, but the`repartition` is also expensive.

Is there a way to solve the partition problem wisely?

Answer (score 4):

You are right,

Repartition is really expensive to run. Due to shuffles and other minor steps. Creating an example as you example said like this:

```
rdd.map(x => (x, x * x)).repartition(8).reduceByKey(_+_)
```

See the DAG here:

[image]

This step will create at DAG, one map, one repartition and one reduce.

But if you use the repartition inside the `reduceByKey` you can take a repartition for "free".

The main part of Repratition is the Shuffle, and the main part of reduceByKey is the shuffle too. You can see that in Scala lib, the `reduceByKey` has a numPartition [parameter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions@reduceByKey(func:(V,V)=%3EV,numPartitions:Int):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,V)]).

So you can change your code for this:

```
rdd.map(x => (x, x * x)).reduceByKey(_+_, 8)
```

[image]

And you can see the same code with the repartition in the `reduceByKey` it is much faster. Due to you have one less shuffle to do.

[image]

Comment: Is it more efficient use `reduceByKey(_+_, 8)` than to use `repartition` for large amounts of data?

Comment: For sure. The repartition + reducebykey create 2 shuffles. Reducebykey with repartition inside the call it creates just 1 shuffle

Comment: If  I run `sc.textFile("data", 20)`, then `reduceByKey(_+_, 20)` is this correct or `reduceByKey(_+_)`?

Comment: In reduce by key, if you want to add a partition better is to change the number of partition. If you set same number of partition that you already have. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: When I have 20 partitions and (key, value) pairs, the key has a value of 1 to 5, and the value has millions of values, If I use `reduceByKey(_+_, 20)`, only 5 of the 20 partitions are used. because it is key standard. But there are 20 partitions, so it is too wasteful to use millions of data in 5 partitions. Is there any way to get all the partitions working?

Comment: If you think of the real underlying situation, both the approaches should be equivalent. Issue with optimization or rather lack of optimization (rdd).

Answer (score 3):

You have to distinguish between two different problems:

**Data skew**

If data distribution is highly skewed (let's assume the worst case scenario with only a single unique key) then by definition the output will be skewed and changing a partitioner cannot help you.

There are some techniques, which can be used to partially address the problem, but overall partitioning is not a core issue here.

**Partitioner bias**

Poorly chosen partitioning function can result in a skewed data distribution even if data is uniformly distributed. For example:

```scala
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq((5, None), (10, None), (15, None), (20, None)), 5)
rdd
  .partitionBy(new org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner(5))
  .glom.map(_.size).collect
```

```
Array[Int] = Array(4, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

As you can see despite the fact that key distribution is not skewed, skewed has been induced by the data regularities and poor properties of the `hashCode`.

In case like this choosing different `Partitioner`:

```scala
rdd
  .partitionBy(new org.apache.spark.RangePartitioner(5, rdd))
  .glom.map(_.size).collect
```

```
Array[Int] = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 0)
```

or adjusting properties of the existing one:

```scala
rdd
  .partitionBy(new org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner(7))
  .glom.map(_.size).collect
```

```
Array[Int] = Array(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1)
```

can resolve the issue.